# pdo statement to return more than 1 column in php

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to fetch values from a mysql query using PDO...it works with one column but I need to return 2 columns from the query. Below is the piece of code I have made...

```
try {
      $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', 'root', '****'>setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $sth = $conn->prepare("select  distinct prod_url,ean from tab_nl where ean in (select ean1 from test_sku where sku='$sku') and prod_url like '%prijzen%'");
$sth->execute();

$urlsku = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$urlean = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
echo $sku;
echo $urlsku;
echo $urlean;
```

It returns me some array values...which I really can't figure out. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: You want get 2 columns or 2nd column ?

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty...2 columns

Comment: You should add the array result also , that would help us to solve quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $data[0]['prod_url'];
echo $data[0]['ean'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `fetch()` with the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` style it is easy to get both columns:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    echo $row['prod_url'];
    echo $row['ean'];
}
```

By placing the fetch in a loop all of the rows will be returned which you can then limit as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Add LIMIT 2 in the query , to get two sets of result :)

```
try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=****', 'root', '****'>setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $sth = $conn->prepare("select  distinct prod_url,ean from tab_nl where ean in (select ean1 from test_sku where sku='$sku') and prod_url like '%prijzen%' LIMIT 2");
$sth->execute();

$urlsku = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 0);
$urlean = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 1);
print_r($urlsku);
print_r($urlean);
```

Comment: If you do not loop through the results the two rows will not be returned. Besides, [the OP wanted *"2 columns"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044648/pdo-statement-to-return-more-than-1-column-in-php/35044933#comment57813567_35044648), not 2 rows according to their clarifying comments.